# Angular 2 app base initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

How can I make basic initialization of my data in app. For example if user logged in and press <kbd>F5</kbd> I need to request current user data from server before all queries starts like get user order etc. In Angular 1 we have  `.run()` directive for this case. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There are probably many ways, but your question is quite vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do that:

- You could execute some requests before bootstrapping your Angular2 application. Such first requests could rely what you save into the local / session storage.

  ```
  var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
  var http = injector.get(Http);

  http.get('/userdetails').map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      bootstrap(AppComponent, [
      HTTP_PROVIDERS
      provide('userDetails', { useValue: data })
    ]);
  });
  ```

  See this question for more details:

  - [How to bootstrap an Angular 2 application asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180108/how-to-bootstrap-an-angular-2-application-asynchronously/36183631#36183631)
- You could extend the HTTP request to transparently get these data when requests are actually executed. This would be a lazy approach.

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class CustomHttp extends Http {
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) {
      super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
      console.log('request...');
      return this.userDetailsService.getUserDetails().flatMap((userDetails) => {
        return super.request(url, options);
      });
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
  console.log('get...');
      return this.userDetailsService.getUserDetails().flatMap((userDetails) => {
        return super.get(url, options);
      });
    }
  }
  ```

  implement the `UserDetailsDetails` this way:

  ```
  export class UserDetailsService {
    constructor(private http:Http) {
    }

    getUserDetails() {
      if (this.userDetails) {
        return Observable.of(this.userDetails);
      } else {
        return this.http.get(...)
           .map(...)
           .do(data => {
             this.userDetails = data;
             // Store in local storage or session storage
           });
      }
    }
  ```

  and register this `CustomHttp` class this way:

  ```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    UserDetailsService,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend,
                   defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
                   userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions, userDetailsService),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, UserDetailsService]
    })
  ]);
  ```

  See these questions for more details:

  - [Angular 2 - How to get Observable.throw globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439672/angular-2-how-to-get-observable-throw-globally/35439805#35439805)
  - [Cache custom component content in ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987514/cache-custom-component-content-in-ionic-2/35987792#35987792)
- Things could also be done at the level of the router outlet if you use routing. It's possible to implement a custom router-outlet that checks security / user details when a route is activated. I think that it's a little further from your need...

  See this question for more details:

  - [Angular 2 Cancelling Route Navigation on UnAuthenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968386/angular-2-cancelling-route-navigation-on-unauthenticate/35968606#35968606)

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch the current user data before you call Angular2's `bootstrap(...)`

You could also fire an event (using an `Observable` for example) to notify other that the logged-in user is now known and initiate further requests only after this event was received.